# Two problems with bidi polyglossia footnotes

Tags: footnotes, polyglossia, bidi

This MWE shows two problems I am encountering with footnotes when using polyglossia (`mainlanguage` Arabic, `otherlanguage` English).

Notice how the punctuation in the footnote reverses position next to the numbers; and notice also the font size is based on the Arabic font sizes, not the English font environment within which the footnotes occur.  The first problem (punctuation) I think must be a bug.  The second might be deliberate, but I don't know.

The output is like this.
[image: Imgur]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale = 3]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}
This is  a   sentence with a footnote. \LTRfootnote{\textenglish{English 1; 2, 3:  
This has the correct font size and the correct punctuation}} 


This is  a  second sentence with a footnote. \LTRfootnote{English 1; 2, 3:  
The punctuation has been mixed and the font size is based on the scaled-up Arabic  3 size} 

\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be illustrated with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\englishfont
English 1; 2, 3:  
The punctuation has been mixed and the font size is based on the scaled-up Arabic  3 size

\bigskip
\arabicfont
English 1; 2, 3:  
The punctuation has been mixed and the font size is based on the scaled-up Arabic  3 size
\end{document}
```

When the font contains `Script=Arabic`, the XeTeX engine will perform some unicode bidi. At the engine level, it is not a bug but a feature.

The `bidi` package only provides the `\LTRfootnote` command and does not set any font so it is polyglossia bug that fails to set proper font for `\LTRfootnote`. I do not know how font set-up works in poly... but you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale = 3]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}\englishfont#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{english}
This is  a   sentence with a footnote. \LTRfootnote{\textenglish{English 1; 2, 3:  
This has the correct font size and the correct punctuation}} 


This is  a  second sentence with a footnote. \LTRfootnote{English 1; 2, 3:  
The punctuation has been mixed and the font size is based on the scaled-up Arabic  3 size} 

\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Be aware that this is not a perfect solution.